# Why doesn't this command work as an alias?

Tags: command-line, bash, alias, awk

I've been using the following command to list the ten largest files, at any depth, under the current directory:

```
find -type f -size +10M -exec ls -gGsSh1 {} + | awk 'NR<=10 {print $0}'
```

(I use `awk` instead of `head` to prevent a [broken pipe error](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/question-shell-gurus-about-unexpected-head-behavior-help-201913202.html) when the list is too long)

It works well, but it's evidently hard to remember and type every time. I tried putting this in .bash_aliases, but it doesn't work then (it prints 10 empty lines).

If I use `less` instead of `awk`, the output is presented correctly, but that means showing the whole list of files bigger than 10MB (my lower threshold), sorted by size, rather than only the top ones.

So, what's making `awk` choke as part of an aliased command here (assuming that's indeed the problem), and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using this command as an alias, `$0` is no more protected by the single quotes so is converted to your shell name. These commands demonstrate it:

```
$ alias F="echo '$0'"      
$ F
bash
```

The shell name (presumably `bash`) happen to be an unset *awk* variable name, leading to the empty lines.

One way to protect `$0` from shell expansion would be to use something like:

```
alias F="find -type f -size +1k -exec ls -gGsSh1 {} + | awk 'NR<=10 {print \$0}'"
```

However, as this `$0` is useless, you can just remove it from the `awk` statement.

```
find -type f -size +10M -exec ls -gGsSh1 {} + | awk 'NR<=10 {print}'
```

You can go further and remove the whole block as printing the selected line is `awk` default behavior anyway:

```
find -type f -size +10M -exec ls -gGsSh1 {} + | awk 'NR<=10'
```

Alternatively, you can just keep using `head` and discard the error message:

```
find -type f -size +10M -exec ls -gGsSh1 {} + 2>&1 | head
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! Also, TIL a new awk trick :D (not that I knew many, though :P)

Comment: @jlliagre - actually `$0` here is not a shell name as it is protected by `'` and passed verbatim to awk. It denotes the whole line in shell (Change it to `$1` and you'll see first record of line not first argument to shell).

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka You are missing the point. $0 is definitely replaced by the shell name when the command is used as an alias.